# Change the divs height dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

```
function pageSize(what){
    oldHeight = parseInt(document.getElementById('items').style.height);
    if(what == 'bigger') {newHeight = oldHeight + 100};
    if(what == 'smaller'){newHeight = oldHeight - 100};
    document.getElementById('items').style.height = newHeight + 'px';
}
```

Above, I put the JavaScript code which should do the trick... This is the div:

```
<div id="items" style="height: 100%;"></div>
```

And I make it bigger or smaller with

```
<a href="#" onclick="pageSize('bigger')"><img src="img/contentbigger.png" /> Page bigger</a> &nbsp; <a href="#" onclick="pageSize('smaller')"><img src="img/contentsmaller.png" /> Pagina smaller</a>
```

But this code does nothing in the newest Mozilla Firefox neither the newest Internet Explorer.

Does somebody see what's wrong here? Because I'm not really that good with JavaScript.

Comment: Consider using jQuery, where `.height()` will give you a reliable value and a reliable possibility to set it

Answer (score 2):

I guess `parseInt()` applied on a string like `<numeric>px` or `<numeric>%` has bogus return values. You should omit to append `px` to your height to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, but how should I do that??

Answer (score 2):

Use element.offsetHeight instead of element.style.height. OffsetHeight will be a number too, so no need to parseInt.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to get rid of the `px` or `em` strings when getting the `oldHeight`:

```
function pageSize(what) {
  oldHeight = document.getElementById('items').style.height.replace('px','').replace('em','');
  oldHeight = parseInt(oldHeight);
  if(what == 'bigger') {newHeight = oldHeight + 100};
  if(what == 'smaller'){newHeight = oldHeight - 100};
  document.getElementById('items').style.height = newHeight + 'px';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

apply unique IDs to both DIV's. Let's say "left" and "right".
So the code will be like this:

```
<script>
function height() 
{
    var right = document.getElementById('right').clientHeight;
    var left = document.getElementById('left').clientHeight;

    if(right > left)
    {
        document.getElementById('left').style.height = right;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('right').style.height = left;
    }
}
</script>
```

Then just fire the function on the page load

```
<body onload="height()">
```

That should do the trick.